# Query to display mutual friends SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am designing a simple social networking site in asp.net c# and I need a help to get count of mutual friends in a query.

My tables are:

Register:

[image: Register Table]

Friends:

[image: Friends Table]

In `Friends` table, *MyId* and *FriendId* are both user's ID. The difference is to show who offers a friendship to another first.

I tried to write some query like below, but it didn't work correctly.

Query Example:

```
Select count(*) 
from Register R 
where RegisterId in (
                    (select F.FriendId as RegisterId 
                    from Friends f 
                    where f.MyId='" + Session["UserId"] + "' and f.Status=1) 
                    Union 
                    (select F.MyId as RegisterId 
                    from Friends f 
                    where f.FriendId='" + Session["UserId"] + "' and f.Status=1) 
                    union 
                    (select F.FriendId as RegisterId 
                    from Friends f 
                    where f.MyId='" + Session["UserId"] + "' and f.Status=1) 
                    union 
                    (select F.FriendId as RegisterId 
                    from Friends f 
                    where f.MyId='" + Session["UserId"] + "' and f.Status=1)
                    ) 
    and R.RegisterId !='" + Session["UserId"] + "' 
    and R.RegisterId !='" + Session["CurrentProfileId"] + "'
```

Comment: As _Josh Part_ has alluded to humorously, please use the [`Parameters` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx) of the `SqlCommand` object to inject values into your string, instead of string concatenation. It's far safer and cleaner that way.

Answer (score 2):

So, by mutual friends, do you mean that if Alice knows Bob, and Alice knows Charlie, then you want to identify Bob & Charlie as potential friends because they have a mutual friend in Alice?

Visually, we can represent this as:

```
Bob <==> Alice
```

where the <==> represents an entry in the `Friends` table. Similarly:

```
Charlie <==> Alice
```

Alice is common to both friendships, so:

```
Bob <==> Alice <==> Charlie
```

Using the above visual representation, you notice there are two <==> symbols, which means there are 2 instances (aliases) of the `Friends` table at play.

Let's call them `FriendLeft` and `FriendRight`. Join both these tables on the field `MyId` but ensure that `FriendId` is different between the left and right tables. Such as the following query:

```
select 
    RegisterLeft.RegisterId as PotentialFriend1Id 
  , RegisterLeft.Name as PotentialFriend1Name 
  , RegisterRight.RegisterId as PotentialFriend2Id 
  , RegisterRight.Name as PotentialFriend2Name 
  , MutualFriend.Name as MutualFriendName 
from ##Register as RegisterLeft 
  inner join ##Friends as FriendLeft 
    on RegisterLeft.RegisterId = FriendLeft.FriendId 
  inner join ##Friends as FriendRight 
    on FriendLeft.MyId = FriendRight.MyId     -- join left and right instances of the friendship table 
  inner join ##Register as RegisterRight 
    on FriendRight.FriendId = RegisterRight.RegisterId 
  inner join ##Register as MutualFriend 
    on FriendLeft.MyId = MutualFriend.RegisterId 
where FriendLeft.FriendId != FriendRight.FriendId -- but eliminate rows that return the same person
```

### Sample Data & Result

For the given sample data of:

```
create table ##Register 
( 
    RegisterId int 
  , Name varchar(50) 
) 
go 

insert into ##Register values (1, 'Alice') 
insert into ##Register values (2, 'Bob') 
insert into ##Register values (3, 'Charlie') 
go 

create table ##Friends 
( 
    MyId int 
  , FriendId int 
) 
go 

insert into ##Friends values (1, 2) -- Alice   <==> Bob 
insert into ##Friends values (1, 3) -- Alice   <==> Charlie 
insert into ##Friends values (2, 1) -- Bob     <==> Alice 
insert into ##Friends values (3, 1) -- Charlie <==> Alice 
go
```

we get a result of:

```
PotentialFriend1Id PotentialFriend1Name  PotentialFriend2Id PotentialFriend2Name  MutualFriendName
------------------ --------------------- ------------------ --------------------- -----------------
3                  Charlie               2                  Bob                   Alice
2                  Bob                   3                  Charlie               Alice
```

The above correctly identifies Bob and Charlie as potential friends with Alice as a mutual friend.

### Commutative Friendships

Do note how I've entered the data in the `Friends` table - I've reflected the relationship both ways to treat the friendship as commutative, so a pair of `(1, 2)` is matched by an equivalent `(2, 1)`. This makes the query simpler.

This also means the result gives you two rows for a single potential friendship - as we see above, we get a result of `(Bob, Charlie)` and `(Charlie, Bob)` which is essentially the same potential friendship. Given you are running this query for either Bob or Charlie (to show a list of "people you might know") you will anyway be filtering on the field `PotentialFriend1Id`. If you aren't, then you can eliminate this doubling by adding a clause to ensure that `PotentialFriend1Id` is less than (or greater than) `PotentialFriend2Id`. Either condition will remove the doubled results.

If you don't wish to store two rows in the `Friends` table for a single friendship to represent friendships in each direction, then your query becomes dependent on the order in which friends are added, and identifying mutual friends becomes much harder. It might be easier in such a case to create a view that reflects the relationship:

```
CREATE VIEW FriendsReflected AS 
SELECT MyId, FriendId FROM Friends 
UNION 
SELECT FriendId, MyId FROM Friends
```

This way, if `Friends` contains only `{ (1, 2) ; (1, 3) }` , the view will return `{ (1, 2) ; (1, 3) ; (2, 1) ; (3, 1) }`.

---

### Friends of Friends

You've clarified below that if Bob is friends with both Alice and Charlie, and if David is friends with Bob, then David should see Alice and Charlie, they being friends of David's friend Bob.

Given the following sample data:

```
insert into ##Register values (1, 'Alice') 
insert into ##Register values (2, 'Bob') 
insert into ##Register values (3, 'Charlie') 
insert into ##Register values (4, 'David') 
go 

insert into ##Friends values (1, 2) -- Alice   <==> Bob 
insert into ##Friends values (3, 2) -- Charlie <==> Bob 
insert into ##Friends values (2, 1) -- Bob     <==> Alice 
insert into ##Friends values (2, 3) -- Bob     <==> Charlie 
insert into ##Friends values (2, 4) -- Bob     <==> David 
insert into ##Friends values (4, 2) -- David   <==> Bob 
go
```

This models the following relationships of David is friends with Bob, and Bob is friends with both Alice and Charlie:

```
David <==> Bob <==> Alice 
David <==> Bob <==> Charlie
```

Then, the following query is what you'd need:

```
select 
    Myself.Name as Myself 
  , MyFriendsDetails.Name as MyFriend 
  , TheirFriendDetails.Name as MyFriendsFriends 
from ##Register as Myself 
  inner join ##Friends as MyFriends 
    on Myself.RegisterId = MyFriends.MyId 
  inner join ##Register as MyFriendsDetails 
    on MyFriends.FriendId = MyFriendsDetails.RegisterId 
  inner join ##Friends as TheirFriends 
    on MyFriends.FriendId = TheirFriends.MyId 
  inner join ##Register as TheirFriendDetails 
    on TheirFriends.FriendId = TheirFriendDetails.RegisterId 
where Myself. RegisterId != TheirFriendDetails.RegisterId -- Remove cases where the friend's friend is myself
```

as it returns the following results, where it shows the first column as an individual, the second column as his/her friends, and the third column as friends of friends. The last 2 rows specifically show the case for David. However, in general, Bob is at the centre of a star with 3 links to his 3 friends Alice, Charlie and David. Through Bob, each of them are exposed to the other 2, which is why the result has 6 rows in total.

```
Myself        MyFriend      MyFriendsFriends
------------- ------------- --------------------
Alice         Bob           Charlie
Alice         Bob           David
Charlie       Bob           Alice
Charlie       Bob           David
David         Bob           Alice
David         Bob           Charlie
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. However I dont want to find people I may know potentially What I want to do here is that to find the friends who are both my friend and my friend's friend. For example; if Alice and Charlie is Bob's friend, and if Bob is my friend, I must see two friends (Alice and Charlie) as a mutual friends when I look Bob's profile. I try to find common friends.. Thank you again.

Comment: OK, based on that clarification, I've edited my answer above with a section titled **Friends of Friends** that has the query you require.

Comment: I have 3 people as a friend in my app. When I use your query, it shows 55 mutual friends :) There is something wrong here :)