# Combining Two SQL queries with INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, join, inner-join

I am trying to get mutual friends in my friend's new project. There are two different queries and we need to combine them with `INNER JOIN`.

How can I combine these two queries to get mutual friends in the project?

Thank you very much.

Query #1:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [Register] 
WHERE RegisterId IN (SELECT MyId 
                     FROM Friends 
                     WHERE FriendId='" + Session["CurrentProfileId"] + "' 
                       AND Status = 1 
                     UNION 
                     SELECT FriendId 
                     FROM Friends
                     WHERE MyId='" + Session["CurrentProfileId"] + "' 
                       AND Status = 1)
```

Query #2:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [Register] 
WHERE RegisterId IN (SELECT MyId 
                     FROM Friends 
                     WHERE FriendId='" + Session["CurrentProfileId"] + "' 
                       AND Status = 1 
                     UNION 
                     SELECT FriendId 
                     FROM Friends 
                     WHERE MyId='" + Session["CurrentProfileId"] + "' 
                       AND Status = 1
                       AND '" + Session["UserId"] + "' != '" + Session["CurrentProfileId"] + "')
```

[Related Link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41189552/7311373)

Comment: Sample data and desired results are much more helpful than just saying "combine".

Comment: I just shared a "Related Link" at the end of text. DB design is showed in that link. Please help us. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what is the difference between Session[UserId] and Session[CurrentProfileId]. Let's assume that you want to get a list of users who are friends of some particular user @USER_ID, OK?

```
SELECT r.RegisterId,r.Name
FROM Register r
  JOIN Friends f ON f.MyId=r.RegisterId and f.Status=1
WHERE f.FriendId=@USER_ID
UNION
SELECT r.RegisterId,r.Name
FROM Register r
  JOIN Friends f ON f.FriendId=r.RegisterId and f.Status=1
WHERE f.MyId=@USER_ID
```

Comment: What is the difference between this query and "Query #2" ?